# How to disable active audio tracks in the paslibvlc video player

Tags: delphi, audio, pascal, lazarus, libvlc

I am using the "paslibvlc" lib for playing videos on the lazarus and need to use the mute function.
When looking at the documentation, more specifically the "libvlc_audio_set_mute ()" statement I noticed that for transmissions that use digital passthrough (in my case HDMI) the function may not be applicable and audio tracks should be disabled.

> **Warning**
>   This function does not always work. If there is no active audio stream stream,
>   the mute status might not be available. If digital pass-through (S / PDIF, 
>   HDMI ...) is in use, muting may be unapplicable. Also some audio output
>   plugins do not support muting at all.
>   To force silent playback, disable all audio tracks. This is more efficient
>   and reliable than mute.

I have not found how to disable audio tracks. How can I do?

Follow the documentation:

https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__audio.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libvlc_audio_set_track(mediaPlayerReference, -1)`

https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__audio.html#gae013e4cf0ae73c093f1a1da1af765d21